# Excel vba: Array of Ranges of huge numbers, how to delcare

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function that takes ranges from a worksheet and stores them in an array:

```
    Function test() 
     Dim resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Range
     Set resultArray(1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:A1000")
     Set resultArray(2, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("B1:B1000")
     Set resultArray(3, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("C1:C1000")

     Set resultArray(1, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("D1:D1000")
     Set resultArray(2, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("E1:E1000")
     Set resultArray(3, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("F1:F1000")


     test=resultArray
End Function
```

However, I'm not sure what is the right way of declaring the array. If I declare it `As Range` how are the values stored inside? The numbers are huge and even Long can't store them. Are numbers stored `As Variant` if I declare the array `As Range` or as something else? How should I declare the array given my situation?

**What should I choose - declare `As Range` or `As Variant`?**

Comment: Excel doesn't handle "huge numbers" . You may have `Double` or numbers stored as `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about usage of your data, which normally may turn this approach more or less advisable.

About data types: all numerical values in Excel are stored as `Double`. Carefull, sometimes numbers are stored as text, and so, are not handled as numbers. But...

You can't declare your array as `Double`, because you are not building a plain array, but nested arrays. Even if was a plain array, you wouldn't be able to assign all range at once because `Range.Value` returns a `Variant()` and VBA can't cast between different array types. This way, your only option is use `Variant`. You could also use `Range`, but this way you will not cache values, just get range references in an array!

So your only solution is:

```
Function test()
    Dim resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To 2) 'As Variant <- implict
    resultArray(1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:A1000")
    resultArray(2, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("B1:B1000")
    resultArray(3, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("C1:C1000")
    resultArray(1, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("D1:D1000")
    resultArray(2, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("E1:E1000")
    resultArray(3, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("F1:F1000")
    test = resultArray
End Function
```

But, in my opinion, best option is cache all data at once:

```
Function test()
    test = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:F1000")
End Function
```

Appendix - About object/value assignment:

To make an object assignment you will have always to use `Set`.
Using `Let` (which is usually omitted) you assign values. When you try to assign a object to a value, default member is called and if it is a value, it is assigned. If object doesn't have a default member or default member is not a value, you will get runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method. In following example, `obj` will be assigned a `Range` object instance, while `val` will receive range values (all four syntax are exactly the same).
At last `nop` will cause error because `Worksheet` do not have a default property.

```
Set obj = Range(...)
Let val = Range(...).Value
    val = Range(...).Value
Let val = Range(...)
    val = Range(...)
    nop = ActiveSheet
```

At last, VBA treats arrays as values so you may copy entire arrays with single assignment:

```
arr1 = Array(...)
arr2 = arr1 'arr2 will turn a copy of arr1
```

Comment: So if I use `As Variant` then even though I don't state `... = Range(...).Value` it still assigns `Range`'s values? I think I'm okay with just pointers to the data - I need the arrays to later search them for values. My greatest concern is that numbers would somehow get truncated when using `As Range`, but you say it gets stored `As Double`, so that's ok, I guess..

Comment: @ans Check appendix, has some more notes.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now!

Comment: Hey, I've been using your answer and a question arised. If I store the range values, how are they stored in memory and how would I loop thorough them? It's not a Range object, so the `Rows.Count` doesn't work.

Comment: @Ans Values are stored in a 2D array, so you can get rows count with `UBound(vals, 1)` and columns count with `UBound(vals, 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub TestMe()    
    Dim myArr   As Variant    
    myArr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3"))    
    Debug.Print LBound(myArr)
    Debug.Print UBound(myArr)
    Debug.Print myArr(1)
    Debug.Print myArr(2)        
End Sub
```

Note - just be careful, in this example the array will start with `1`, not with `0`. And this is how to do it with a function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print ReturnArray(1)
    Debug.Print ReturnArray(2)
    Debug.Print LBound(ReturnArray); UBound(ReturnArray)
End Sub

Public Function ReturnArray() As Variant
    ReturnArray = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A3"))
End Function
```

If you have your data in one row, to make it 1 dimensional array, you could transpose it twice. [image]

Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim myArr   As Variant
    myArr = ReturnArrayHorizontal
    Debug.Print myArr(1)
    Debug.Print UBound(myArr)
    Debug.Print LBound(myArr)
End Sub

Public Function ReturnArrayHorizontal() As Variant
    With Application
        ReturnArrayHorizontal = .Transpose(.Transpose(Range("A1:E1")))
    End With
End Function
```

**Edit:** To get a multidimensional array from range with many columns and rows, imagine you have the following:

[image]

Then try playing with this:

```
Public Sub Testing()        
    Dim resultArray As Variant        
    resultArray = Range("A1:F10")        
    Debug.Print resultArray(1, 1)
    Debug.Print resultArray(10, 6)        
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do use `Transpose`? What is wrong with my initialization?

Comment: @Ans - transpose allows you to go to 1 dimension.

Comment: @vityata - its usually less efficient to use transpose than to work directly with 2 dimensions

Comment: @Vityata I need more than  1 dimension! That's important to me. Each Range is different, they shouldn't me mixed.

Comment: @Ans - initially your question was about 1 dimension, that's why my answer is so. For two dimensions, just use the range, it makes it automatic.

Comment: @Vityata Range makes automatic what? Would declaring a Variant result in bugs of some sort?

Comment: @Ans - no bug, variant is ok.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you try to achieve but here is a way to define your array

```
Function test() ' returns an array
    Dim resultArray
    resultArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:A1000")
    'resultarray is now an array (1 to 1000,1 to 1)
    test = resultArray
End Function
```

Comment: I try to achieve storing ranges of data in a variable so that it's faster to access. What is wrong with my method? Why don't you use `As` at all?

Comment: You have a 1 column range and you return a 2 dimensional array. That's 1 dimension more.

Comment: @Vityata I set arrays to all dimensions, I just didn't think it was relevant to the question and didn't copy all the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SET then you are effectively storing a pointer to the range object rather than the values that the range contains. You can use SET with a variant, which will then contains a range object pointer, or more directly you can use SET with a range variable.

To retrieve the data the most efficient way is to assign range.value2 to a variant. You don't need to dimension the variant or use Transpose - the variant will contain a 2-dimensional array of variants.

Comment: Thank you. What would be more efficient, given that I would need to search through those ranges later - store the pointers or the values?

Comment: There is a large overhead for each call from VBA to Excel, so its usually much more efficient to work with variant arrays of values.